# Is it possible to merge two Debezium connectors?

Tags: mysql, debezium

Dealing with large MySQL DBs (10s TB), I find myself having to split up a connector so I can process more rows at a time (every single connector can process one table a time).

Once the `initial` sync is complete, and it switches to incremental, what is the cleanest way of merging the two connectors?

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Since both connectors are created with different `database.server.name` values, their associated topics are likely prefixed with different values and so attempting to merge multiple connectors would be highly cumbersome and error-prone.

What I would suggest is if you have a large volume of data that you need to snapshot, don't rely on the initial snapshot phase to capture the data.  Instead, configure a single connector to use the `schema_only` snapshot mode so that the schemas get captured before streaming starts.  Then you can leverage incremenal snapshots that run in parallel with streaming to capture the 10TB of data concurrently.

Comment: Thanks @Naros you have two every interesting point I'd love if you could expand in your answer: 1) if I created two (or more) different connectors with diffeerent names and exactly identical for all other configurations except a non overlapping `table.include.list`, but keeping the same `database.server.name`, do you think I could obtain the same goal? 2) From an operability perspective, in which case using `initial` would be any better than `schema_only` + `incremental_snapshot`?

Comment: No, unfortunately you can't do that at least not concurrently.  All connectors except PG use a database history topic where the `database.server.name` is part of the topic's name and so sharing the same value across multiple connectors concurrently will cause potential corruption or problems with that topic.

Comment: could you please help me understand one case in which it can cause corruption if they handle non-overlapping tables?

Comment: First it's not a supported configuration by Debezium.  Secondly, by default, a connector tracks all schema changes to the source and so if you have multiple connectors likely reading from different binlog positions, you run the risk of a `CREATE TABLE` followed by an `ALTER TABLE` being sent as `CREATE TABLE`, `CREATE TABLE`, `ALTER TABLE`, `ALTER TABLE` or worse, `CREATE`, `ALTER`, `CREATE`, `ALTER` all for the same table, which might be problematic for how we recover the history topic upon connector restart.

Comment: thanks for bringing that up. I didn't expect that the `all schema changes` were tracked not considering the `table.include.list`

Comment: The `table.include.list` explicitly controls what events we emit change events for.  For schema changes, you can control this by using `database.history.store.only.captured.tables.ddl` as `true`; however, this can be problematic in the future if you decide to add new tables to the include list as the schema topic won't reflect the history associated with the new table if it was created prior to it being added to the include list.

Comment: Gotcha. As a lesson it seems that 1) if your system allows GTID, incremental snapshot should work best 2) otherwise having multiple (partitioned) source/sink connectors with different `database.server.name` might be the solution for old systems.

Comment: Both have their share of advantages and disadvantages, but yes where possible with large volumes of data, incremental snapshots is most definitely the better alternative.